# python json2xml library not working as expected

Tags: python, json, serialization

I am using this library [json2xml](https://pypi.org/project/json2xml/) to convert a json string to xml, but its not working as expected.

This is the code simplified

```
from json2xml import json2xml
from json2xml.utils import readfromstring

json_str= """
{
  "Parent": {
    "Fruits": [
      {
        "Apples": 1,
        "grapes": "2kilos",
        "Extra": {
          "PurchaseDate": "2023-09-25",
          "Location":"warehouse"
        }
        
      },
      {
        "Apples": 2,
        "grapes":"5kilos",
        "Extra": {
          "PurchaseDate": "2023-09-25",
          "Location":"Residence"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
"""
json_body = readfromstring(json_str)
json_xml = json2xml.Json2xml(json_body, attr_type=False, item_wrap=False).to_xml()
print(json_xml)
```

This is the actual output

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<all>
        <Parent>
                <Fruits>
                        <Apples>1</Apples>
                        <grapes>2kilos</grapes>
                        <Extra>
                                <PurchaseDate>2023-09-25</PurchaseDate>
                                <Location>warehouse</Location>
                        </Extra>
                        <Apples>2</Apples>
                        <grapes>5kilos</grapes>
                        <Extra>
                                <PurchaseDate>2023-09-25</PurchaseDate>
                                <Location>Residence</Location>
                        </Extra>
                </Fruits>
        </Parent>
</all>
```

Shouldn't it be this where the Fruits is repeated like this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<all>
        <Parent>
                <Fruits>
                        <Apples>1</Apples>
                        <grapes>2kilos</grapes>
                        <Extra>
                                <PurchaseDate>2023-09-25</PurchaseDate>
                                <Location>warehouse</Location>
                        </Extra>
                </Fruits>
                <Fruits>
                        <Apples>2</Apples>
                        <grapes>5kilos</grapes>
                        <Extra>
                                <PurchaseDate>2023-09-25</PurchaseDate>
                                <Location>Residence</Location>
                        </Extra>
                </Fruits>
        </Parent>
</all>
```

Setting `item_wrap=True` adds an extra value called item which is not expected.
This is the result of setting `item_wrap=True`. How to replace `<item>` with `<Fruits>` ?

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<all>
        <Parent>
                <Fruits>
                        <item>
                                <Apples>1</Apples>
                                <grapes>2kilos</grapes>
                                <Extra>
                                        <PurchaseDate>2023-09-25</PurchaseDate>
                                        <Location>warehouse</Location>
                                </Extra>
                        </item>
                        <item>
                                <Apples>2</Apples>
                                <grapes>5kilos</grapes>
                                <Extra>
                                        <PurchaseDate>2023-09-25</PurchaseDate>
                                        <Location>Residence</Location>
                                </Extra>
                        </item>
                </Fruits>
        </Parent>
</all>
```

**NOTE:** This incoming json is dynamic and can have different types of elements that need to be mapped, so I can't always expect Fruits to be present. It could be Meats or some other array or non-array element everytime the application runs.